# Why can't I use Application.WorksheetFunction.Year() on a date or long?

Tags: excel, vba

I was tired and accidentally tried to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Year()` instead of `Year()` in VBA, but this still puzzled me and I'm trying to figure out why this errors out. Take the following code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim mydate As Date

    'In cell A1 on the activesheet is the short date "12/30/2019"
    mydate = Range("A1").Value

    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Year(mydate)

End Sub
```

When `maxdate` is a `Date`, this results in

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

When `maxdate` is a `Long`, it results in the same error. Just for kicks I tried `Integer` (which obviously doesn't work since the serial number of a date is bigger than the `Integer` cap) so you get an overflow error.

Why can't I use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Year()` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Month()` here? I also tried using `CLng()` to convert it to what I thought the function was expecting, same results (Run-time error '438').

Comment: Not an answer, but one way to get VBA to use the worksheetfunction would be: `Debug.Print [YEAR(A1)]`, obviously some other form of "worksheetfunction".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Year` method of `WorksheetFunction`, as Intellisense or the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) will quickly show. Since the `VBA.Year` and `VBA.Month` functions already exist, there is no need for a `WorksheetFunction` version.

Just use the `Year` function.

Comment: I thought any formula in Excel was a member of `WorksheetFunction` - how can I know which are and which aren't?

Comment: Intellisense should help.

Comment: @dwirony if there is a natural vba that does the same then there is no worksheetfunction version.

Comment: ^ `Round` being one exception, though `WorksheetFunction.Round` and `Round` don't operate the same way so maybe that's not really an exception.

Comment: Trim and worksheetfunction.trim also exist but they do different things.

Comment: Ah... I'm surprised I hadn't run into this issue before. Good to know!

Comment: @BigBen Funny about the Intellisense, I was annoyed because it kept autopopulating to `YearFrac()`, I thought it was bugging out! Haha

Comment: Haha yes that would be annoying.